# rails_admin authentication with user's boolean admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-admin

I am currently using rails 4.2.0beta4 with devise. In my schema, my user had boolean :admin default:false. After installing rails_admin, for the time being, every user is allowed to go to my /admin. But how do I make it so that only the users with boolean is_admin? true people log in?

Should I just do rails generate devise admin? Would that be quicker choice than having to configure again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an admin namespace...
1 - In routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :your_routes
end
```

2 - Make sure the following directories exist; app/views/admin, app/controllers/admin, and put any controllers and view templates that you want to restrict to admins in those folders.

3 - Add this to application_controller.rb

```
def user_is_admin?
  signed_in? && current_user.is_admin?
end
```

4 - Then in any controller inside your app/controllers/admin add a before_filter to check
some_controller.rb

```
class Admin::YourController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :user_is_admin?
end
```

For what it's worth, you don't have to namespace if you don't want to. You could technically just add the before_filter from steps 3 and 4 to whatever action you want to protect, but I think the namespace is a better idea in the long run.